# Create new AspNetUsers object requires ID MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a new AspNetUsers object as an admin account to my project.
In my Global.asax I call a static method which shall generate that user. I'm doing it that way:

```
if (!db_entities.AspNetUsers.Any(u => u.Email.Equals("text")))
{
    PasswordHasher hasher = new PasswordHasher();
    string adminPassword = "test";

    AspNetUsers adminAccount = new AspNetUsers
    {
        Email = "text",
        UserName = "text",
        PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(adminPassword),
        SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    };

    db_entities.AspNetUsers.Add(adminAccount);
    db_entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

When this method is called, a `DbEntityValidationException` appears and tells me in the inner exception that the Id field is required.
Actually I'm using the "same" code to create objects in other parts of my project and the Id is imho always delivered by the system. I found a post on that to first call `SaveChanges()` but it didn't work cause the Id is always missing.

Comment: Do you have Auto Increment set to ON for `AspNetUsers` table in database

Comment: Ah, due to its automated generation I didn't check that. It's not set to Auto Increment, because it's not an identity. But it's an nvarchar-Id with many characters. Is there probably a way to increment that by itself or do I need to write a tool to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Auto Increment ON` for `AspNetUsers` table in database and refresh the database entities in `edmx`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot just change the Id from NVarchar to Int. When I was trying to update the edmx I got many errors due to mapping the fields where I couldn't choose Int.